# Does AppDomain.RelativeSearchPath replacement in .NET Core exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have following code to retrieve application binary directory in desktop .NET Framework:

```
static string GetBinDirectory()
{
    var relativePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
    var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(relativePath) || !relativePath.IsSubdirectoryOf(basePath)
        ? basePath
        : relativePath;
}
```

This code works correct in corner cases like assembly shadow copying running NUnit tests.
I started migration this code to .NET Core platform.

I found that there is `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` property in ASP.NET Core.

Which is the way to get correct path to application binaries in pure .NET Core?

Which is the replacement for `AppDomain.RelativeSearchPath` property?

Comment: More AppDomain API surface is coming back to .NET Core (https://jeremydmiller.com/2016/05/31/my-surprisingly-positive-take-on-net-cores-current-direction/) so I rather wait for more info from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath` which is the path to the folder the application lives in.